# Chaining C# LINQ , in a Rails-scope-like way

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class where I store some static data. I have as well a couple methods to filter that data, using LINQ. Like this:

```
static class Data {

    // ...

    static public Weapon[] weapons = new Weapon[] {
        // ...
    }

    static public GetUnlockedWeapons() {
        Data.weapons.Where( a => a.unlocked ).ToArray();
    }

    static public GetWeaponsType(string type) {
        Data.weapons.Where( a => a.type == type ).ToArray();
    }

// ...
}
```

But now I am seeing that this way is not very flexible. As I build more filters, combining them is quite hard and/or verbose.

I come from Ruby on Rails development, where there ActiveRecord has something like `scopes` that are chainable.

I was wondering if there was some way for me to `chain` my filters, in a way similar to this:

```
weapons = Data.weapons.unlocked().type("sword").andMore().andEvenMore();
```

Comment: Change your array Weapon[] to a List<Weapon> which gives you more filter options.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how Lists are better?

Comment: List are enhanced arrays where lots of additional methods were added.  Simply create a list object and then look at the methods that are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
static class Data {

    // ...

    static public Weapon[] weapons = new Weapon[] {
        // ...
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Weapon> GetUnlockedWeapons(this IEnumerable<Weapon> weapons) {
        return weapons.Where( a => a.unlocked );
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Weapon> GetWeaponsType(this IEnumerable<Weapon> weapons, string type) {
        return weapons.Where( a => a.type == type );
    }

// ...
}
```

And using it:

```
var weapons = Data.weapons.GetUnlockedWeapons().GetWeaponsType("pistol").AndMore().ToList();
```

There's no point returning an Array, since it's likely you'll chain it. Leave the materialization of the collection up to the caller (in this case we're using `ToList`)

Comment: I see twice the word `public` in `GetUnlockedWeapons`. Typo?

Comment: Yep sorry - the second one should be removed

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about defining your filters as [`extension methods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to the `IEnumerable<Weapon>` type:

```
public static class Data 
{
    public Weapon[] GetUnlockedWeapons(this IEnumerable<Weapon> weapons)
    {
        return weapons.Where( a => a.unlocked ).ToArray();
    }

    public static Weapon[] GetWeaponsType(this IEnumerable<Weapon> weapons, string type)
    {
        return weapons.Where( a => a.type == type ).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and now assuming that you have a list of weapons you could apply those filters to it:

```
Weapon[] weapons = new Weapon[] 
{
    // ...
};

weapons = weapons.unlocked().type("sword").andMore().andEvenMore();
```

Alternatively you could define an API that is using the so called *fluent interface*:

```
public class Data 
{
    public Data(Weapon[] weapons)
    {
        this.Weapons = weapons;
    }

    public Weapon[] weapons { get; private set; }

    public Data GetUnlockedWeapons()
    {
        return new Data(this.Weapons.Where( a => a.unlocked ).ToArray());
    }

    public Data GetWeaponsType(this IEnumerable<Weapon> weapons, string type) 
    {
        return new Data(this.Weapons.Where( a => a.type == type ).ToArray());
    }
}
```

and then use like this:

```
Weapon[] weapons = new Weapon[] 
{
    // ...
};

weapons = new Data(weapons).unlocked().type("sword").andMore().andEvenMore().Weapons;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static class WeaponFilters
    {
         public static Weapon[] GetUnlocked(this Weapon[] w)
        {
             return w.Where(x=> x.unlocked).ToArray();
        }
         public static Weapon[] Type(this Weapon[] w, string type)
        {
             return w.Where(x=> x.type == type).ToArray();
        }
   //some more filters...
    }
```

Then You can use it like:

```
weapons = weapons.unlocked().type("sword");
```